# an IXMLDOMAttribute as return value of a VBScript function

Tags: vbscript, msxml

I'm creating XML documents with VBScript and MSXML DOM. In order to structure and simplify my code I'm using classes and thus methods (functions in VBS) too.

Here is a little function that troubles me:

```
function createAttribute(name, value)

dim doc 
Set doc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0")

dim attr 
set attr= doc.createNode(2,name,"")
attr.NodeValue=value

createAttribute=attr

end function
```

The assignment `createAttribute=attr`, where I'm setting the return value of the function, causes the following error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

As the web resources on XML processing with VBS are rather sparse, I hope some of you can help me to understand whats going on here. Here are my questions:

What object does not support what property or method?

Can i pass objects of any given class as return values of VBS functions?

Can i pass an object of the class `IXMLDOMAttribute` as a return value to a VBS function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that `attr` is an object, so you need to use `set` to apply the return value. Otherwise, you may simply be returning `attr`'s default property value (if it has one):

```
set createAttribute = attr
```

You don't show how you use the return value, so I can't comment on that but it is possibly the  source of the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The missing 'set' was the source for my problem.